# Having Separate Certificates Running Under GlassFish 2

Tags: web-services, glassfish, open-esb

Can anyone please explain how i can have more than one X.509 Certificates in my GlassFish application server?
The main challenge for me is that GlassFish uses just one alias which is 's1as'.

Comment: can you elaborate on the purpose of the additional certificates you want to use? Is that to use as an SSL client certificate?

Comment: Sure, I have a couple of services on my GlassFish. These service will be invoking different external services which requires SSL authentication hence the additional certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull additional certificates from external key files to create an `SSLContext` and then `SSLSocketFactory`, which you can feed into your external HTTPS calls.

E.g.:

```
KeyStore cKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
try (InputStream clientCertKeyInput = new FileInputStream("my.pfx")) {
     cKeyStore.load(clientCertKeyInput, "password".toCharArray());
}
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(cKeyStore, "password".toCharArray());

SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslCtx.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), 
            null, // default javax.net.ssl.trustStore
            new SecureRandom()); 

SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslCtx.getSocketFactory();
```

You may then configure an `HttpsURLConnection` with it:

```
httpsConn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
```

Or if you're using JAXWS set it as a property of the `BindingProvider`'s context:

```
Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
ctxt.put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, sslSocketFactory);
```

Hope this helps.